# Kernel keeps dying and restarting when running some lines in python Notebook

Tags: linux-kernel, jupyterhub

I get the error -->

```
/apps/anaconda3/bin/python: symbol lookup error: /apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mkl/../../../libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs
```

To fix this, I tried updating mkl package by doing a "`conda update mkl`", and then restarting the jupyterhub service.  But still, the issue persists.

the libmkl_intel_thread.so file is located in the below paths -

```
/apps/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so
/apps/anaconda3/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so
/apps/anaconda3/pkgs/mkl-2017.0.1-0/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so
/apps/anaconda3/pkgs/mkl-2019.4-243/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so
```

my $PATH is -->

```
/apps/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/bin:/apps/anaconda3/condabin:/apps/anaconda3/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin:/apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/apps/anaconda3/envs/myEnv:/apps/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/bin:/apps/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Looks like you are missing `libiomp5.so`. Instead of updating, can you run `conda update intel-openmp`? Also make sure the file is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Have a look at this bug report: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10195

Comment: @4ndy - Thanks; but unfortunately, the issue persists and gives the same error, related to  omp_get_num_procs

Comment: @4ndy, I was able to fix it finally... like it was mentioned in the bug report you shared, I did a "conda update intel-openmp", but this time after switching out of the active conda env, by doing a "conda deactivate".  This fixed the issue.  I am accepting your answer, and thanks again...

Comment: Thank you, I have made it the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing libiomp5.so. Instead of updating, can you run `conda update intel-openmp`? Also make sure the file is in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Have a look at this bug report: [github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10195](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10195)

Comment: worked for me, but I had to force it with: conda install --force-reinstall intel-openmp